# Best expression for 'hesitation towards sharing'

Tags: expressions

Can someone suggest some good expressions or simple sentences to express to someone when he's hesitating to share knowledge, especially when he already possesses adequate amount of information on the matter concerned?

I can think of

> 'Oh, stop being such a miser'

. But I don't think 'miser' is the right word for it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possessive? selfish? secretive? It may matter *why* he doesn’t want to share.

Comment: Possessive / secretive sounds perfect in my case, I think. Thanks @StephenS